# Issues with running "Test ANTLR rule" on start rule in IntelliJ with ANTLR plugin

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to run a simple grammar file in IntelliJ with the ANTLR v4 grammar plugin on a new computer. I have followed the online steps for installing the plugin in IntelliJ, and the plugin looks like it is installed correctly. I have written simple code in a .g4 grammar file, and clicked the option to generate an ANTLR recognizer on the code. However, when I try to run the grammar file on the start rule by right-clicking the start rule, the option "Test ANTLR rule" is greyed out. When I look at the .g4 file, it does not show the ANTLR "red A" icon, but instead an icon with curly braces for generic files.

I have uninstalled and re-installed IntelliJ twice, uninstalled and in-installed the ANTLR v4 grammar plugin multiple times, and tried to find similar posts of this issue. I have been able to get the ANTLR plugin to work in other computers on the same steps, but it is not working for me this time.

```
grammar g;

prule: 'hello ' CHAR;

CHAR: 'a'..'z' | ' ' | 'A'..'Z';
```

After each attempted solution, I expected for the "Test ANTLR rule" option to be available and not greyed out when I right-click the start rule, but each time the option is disabled. Any assistance to be able to run the ANTLR code from the start rule will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (Windows 10).
Updating IntelliJ to 2019 helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

right click the file and choose 'override file type', change it to g4. it seems like you've choosen the file type before you download the plugin